# How to retrieve a large number of specified rows

Tags: sql, oracle, powerbuilder

I'm using PowerBuilder 10.5 and Oracle 7 database.

My problem is next: user goes into the program, retrieves data and gets a DataWindow, with a large number of rows(lets say a 1000), showing amount of money the client has, city he lives in, as well as some other data. The user then clicks all the rows that are of interest to him (some 500) and filters them in a second DataWindow, call it `DW_1`. Now he wants an excel sheet that gives sum of all money grouped by the city where clients live. Important to remember is that I want the sum only for the clients that the user flagged before. So this is what I'm doing in the code:

```
String ls_s,ls_client,ls_clicked_client, ls_sql
Long ll_i
ls_s='';ls_client='';ls_clicked_client='';

FOR ll_i= 1 TO DW_1.RowCount()
 ls_s=DW_1.GetItemString(ll_i, "client")
  IF ll_i<DW_1.RowCount() THEN
    ls_client+="'"+ls_s+"'," 
  ELSEIF ll_i=DW_1.RowCount() THEN
    ls_clicked_client+=ls_client+"'"+ls_s+"'"
  END IF
NEXT

ls_sql="SELECT city, SUM(amount) sum_amount"& 
   +"FROM("&
   +"SELECT city, amount"&  
   +"FROM table1 T1 WHERE amount+0>0 AND client IN ( "+ls_clicked_client+"))"&
   +"GROUP BY city"

DW_1.SetSqlSelect(ls_sql)
DW_1.Retrieve()
w_window.SetMicrohelp(String(DW_1.RowCount()))
DW_1.saveas("excel.xls")
```

As you can see, I'm taking all my flagged clients and putting their client codes into one variable which I then use as my argument in the SQL IN function. After that i use the standard saveas method.

This worked great until I picked out more rows then one can take: once I go over board, I get `ORA 01795: max number of expressions in a list is 1000`. That's my problem: if the user picks too many clients this fails.

I've also tried to use `INSTR` function, but that also failed do to the big amount of selected rows - I get `ORA 01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested` tips: it seems that attempting to pass a string to a bind variable value in excess of 4000 bytes causes it to collapse.

So basically I have something working to some extent which does not satisfy me. And I have no ideas how to make this work without the SQL code I've written in the ls_sql variable. If I was supposed to give just some rows of the `DW_1` in an excel sheet I'd go with OLE objects, but I don't see how to get sum of amounts grouped by city for such a large number of specified clients.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: this smells a bad idea, but did you tried to replace the `in (list)` construction by a succession of `or client = xx`?

Comment: You're tired of hearing that Oracle 7 was desupported 10 years ago, I should think.

Comment: @Seki, didn't think of that, will try when I find time, just to see where that would take me. Report back on it.

Comment: @David, one works with what one gets :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Performance and optimization aside, you can build multiple SELECT statements like the one you have but each statement uses a string that is of a smaller size than 1000. You could then either:

A- issue the statements in a loop or

B- use SELECT.....UNION SELECT....etc. This should overcome the size issue. Again if you have a huge SQL string you may get a problem with the UNION approach.

Comment: Had that idea, but I opted for datastore later: I had the problem of some null values entering in there when I'd go for Union option.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the user-selected-records into another table and then issue a select like this one:

```
SELECT   T1.city, SUM(T1.amount) sum_amount
FROM     table1 T1 
WHERE    T1.amount > 0 
AND      T1.client IN ( select T2.id from your_new_table T2 )
GROUP BY T1.city
```

Comment: This is somewhat the line I went for at the end: I created a datastore, where I'd first put my rows. Then I'd just use powerbuilders syntax: datastore.SetSort(ciy), datastore.Sort() and after that I set a loop where I'm inserting cities and and summing amount for them. I'll put the code when I find time, so you could see. Thanks for the answer.